# Issue with generating EAN128 code using Barcode4j for multiple sets of AI and data

Tags: java, barcode4j

I'm using barcode4j to generate EAN128 barcode.
The barcode I need to generate contains multiple sets of Application Identifiers and data, for example:

```
(410)000061000034(412)000001101593
```

The data length for both `410` and `412` is `13 characters`.
I'm using add checksum mode, so as you can see in above example I only intend to provide 12 characters as the data for each AI and would expect a checksum digit would be calculated and automatically appended.

However by using below code, it does NOT generate the correct code for me:

```
    dpi = 200;
    // barcode
    objEAN128Bean.setModuleWidth(0.21);
    objEAN128Bean.setHeight(15);
    // objEAN128Bean.setWideFactor(3);
    objEAN128Bean.doQuietZone(true);
    objEAN128Bean.setQuietZone(2);
    // human-readable
    objEAN128Bean.setFontName("Helvetica");
    objEAN128Bean.setFontSize(3);
    // checksum
    objEAN128Bean.setChecksumMode(objCheckSum.CP_ADD);
    BitmapCanvasProvider canvas = new BitmapCanvasProvider(out,
                "image/jpeg", dpi, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, true, 0);
    objEAN128Bean.generateBarcode(canvas, "410000061000034412000001101593");
    canvas.finish();
```

It looks like the `barcode4j` does NOT know where the data of the first `AI (410)` ends and thus does NOT correctly identify the second set of AI and data.

I found there is a way to do it by using the XML approach specifying sth like:

```
<template>(410)n12+cd1(412)n12+cd1</template>
```

I'm just wondering if anyone knows a solution by using the Java bean approach?

Any help and shed of light would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's too late for this answer but I've solved it just by adding the template to the **objEAN128Bean**:

```
objEAN128Bean.setTemplate("(415)n13+(8020)n18+(3902)n10+cd");
```

and it will bind the string properly.

Comment: Thank You! Other documentation I've been reading now makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is relevant for you, but in Jasper report's barcode4j component, you can start a new application identifier with the `\u00f1` character.

```
"97XXX\u00f1916213514687"
```

It will give you a barcode like

```
(97) XXX (91) 6213514687
```

Comment: Yes. In barcode4j barcodes, you can "enter" a 2nd, 3rd, etc. Application Identifier by prefixing its "code" with either an ASCII 29 (hex : 0x1D) character, or a ñ character. For instance 97XXX<GS>916213514687 or 97XXXñ916213514687  will result in barcodes with 97 and 91 AI.